# sudo: unable to execute ... bad address - what is it and how to fix it?

Tags: bash, mac-osx, sudo, hostname

I have a set of scripts which finishes up client machine deployment after executing a fairly generic NetRestore image.

The main script runs under root privileges, and then calls another, "user" script with `sudo -iu $PROPER_USER ...`

The problem is, sudo fails on this step and doesn't actually execute the script. I get this error:

```
sudo: unable to execute /bin/bash: Bad address
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix this? One thing that comes to mind is that I'm changing the hostname earlier in the script, using `networksetup -setcomputername ...`

Comment: Once check your script shebang value, is it `#!/bin/bash` or what.  if possible post your script snippet

Comment: I checked, and even checked for stray wrong newlines. Didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind about the networking. It was not even close.

The `Bad address` message comes from the kernel and indicates that a the process attempted to open a terminal (pty/tty) which does not exist.

I'm not sure why adding `sleep` fixed the issue (unreliably), but going back to no-sleep version of my scripts and adding:

`Defaults   !requiretty`

to `/etc/sudoers` works so far.

Cheers!

Comment: That's not what `Bad address` means. What it means is that a program passed an invalid pointer to a system call. For example if `NULL` is given as argument to the `open` system call instead of a file name, then you will get `Bad address`. It could also happen if the pointer is valid, but no NUL character is found before the end of allocated memory. What you are seeing sounds very much like a bug, you should file a bug report.